# Windows 10 Professional goes blank while installing update (Intel Corporation driver update for Intel(R) HD Graphics.)

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, intel-graphics

When windows 10 tries to update itself with Intel Corporation driver update for Intel(R) HD Graphics goes blank with black screen for hours and hours. Need to forcefully restart every time when it goes blank.

No hard disk light and no single action on monitor.

Computer Configuration : Processor: Intel Pentium G2020, Motherboard: Gigabyte H61M-D2H, Hard Disk: SATA 3 Seagate Barracuda 500GB, RAM: Kingstone 4GB DDR3 1600mhz running at 1333mhz, No GPU.

Thank You.

Comment: Could be an issue with the display driver update. Try to see if you can manually download the intel display driver from Intel's website and install it.

Comment: @GaneshR. I did the same what you told but the update still there and still things goes blank.

Comment: If that is the case, the problem is the intel driver. Either your board has an issue, or just the driver is buggy. Block the driver update from Windows Update: http://www.howtogeek.com/223864/how-to-uninstall-and-block-updates-and-drivers-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

**Manually update the driver**

Rather than using Windows update to update your video driver goto the Intel website and get the driver installation package.  It's a setup program that will run through it's configuration and update the driver with an official Intel signed package.

This will be a different driver than the Windows update and will also provide a GUI interface to allow various deeper configuration of your GPU's settings.